# wireguard peer 2 peer slow

Tags: vpn, wireguard

i have a wireguard setup with 1 Server and 2 Peers

The File transfer is somewhat slow when from Peer 2 Peer

Peer 1 to/from Server about 150 Mbps
Peer 2 to/from Server about 150 Mbps

Peer 1 to Peer 2 about 6 Mbps if i am lucky.

Peers and Server are set to use MTU = 1280

Configs:

cat /etc/wireguard/postup.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT

# Traffic forwarding
iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT

#Nat
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE

# DNS
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.1/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.1/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1/24
MTU = 1280
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = xxx
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/postup.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/postdown.sh

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/32, 192.168.100.0/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.3/32, 192.168.200.0/24
```

ip route

```
default via 89.163.xxx.1 dev eno1 onlink 
10.10.10.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.1 
89.163.xxx.1 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 89.163.xxx.xxx 
192.168.100.0/24 dev wg0 scope link 
192.168.200.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
```

All 3 Devices (debian 11) have a CPU usage of 0.1 while testing.

Wireguard Server (dedicated) sitting in a Datacenter.

Peer 1 -> DSL Modem -> ISP -> Datacenter -> Server.

Peer 2 -> DSL Modem -> ISP -> Datacenter -> Server.

All wired connections.

what could be the issue here?

Comment: 1) Why are you using a MTU of 1280? 2) How is each peer connected to the server, physically? Is Wi-Fi involved at any point?

Comment: 1) results of best performance from peer to server. 
2.1) Peer 1 -> DSL Modem -> ISP -> Datacenter -> Server. - 
2.2) Peer 2 -> DSL Modem -> ISP -> Datacenter -> Server

All wired connections.

Comment: @Dennis - [Edit] your question instead of supplying vital required information in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Never found out the actual issue with that, I switched over to tincd and set all 3 devices up with 'mode = switch' and i have full speed accross the board now.